# Should you initialize $matches before calling preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

`preg_match` accepts a `$matches` argument as a reference. All the examples I've seen do not initialize it before it's passed as an argument. Like this:

```
preg_match($somePattern, $someSubject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Isn't this error-prone? What if `$matches` already contains a value? I would think it should be initialized to an empty array before passing it in as an arg. Like this:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match($somePattern, $someSubject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Am i just being paranoid?

Comment: Have you tried it? What's the result?

Comment: @M42 I have, but I've never seen this question formally answered anywhere. It's not mentioned in the preg_match docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to initialise $matches as it will be updated with the results. It is in effect a second return value from the function.

Comment: No, it is passed by reference so it is updated not overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

as Chris Lear said you don't need to initialize `$matches`. But if your pattern contains a capture group you want to use later, it is better to write:

```
$somePattern = '/123(456)/';
if (preg_match($somePattern, $someSubject, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

to avoid the error of undefined index in the result array. However, you can use `isset($matches[1])` to check if the index exists.